# Using AND with the apply function in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Why doesn't the following work?

```
(apply and (list #t #t #f))
```

While the following works just fine.

```
(apply + (list 1 3 2))
```

This seems to be the case in both R5RS and R6RS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`and` isn't a normal function because it will only evaluate as few arguments as it needs, to know whether the result is true or false. For example, if the first argument is false, then no matter what the other arguments are, the result has to be false so it won't evaluate the other arguments. If `and` were a normal function, all of its arguments would be evaluated first, so `and` was made a special keyword which is why it cannot be passed as a variable.

Comment: This is one of my greatest frustrations with Scheme - macros should be first-class. I realize that it may prevent some compilation optimization, but it would definitely increase the expressive power of the language.

Comment: Kyle, you might as well be talking about a language called [_Kernel_](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~jshutt/kernel.html). Kernel aims to address the problem of second class special forms, introducing other abstraction primitives to provide more flexible evaluation semantics. (Compilation optimization could be a problem, as you say.) The example from this question, `and`, is even the "hello world" example shown on the [klisp implementation's homepage](http://klisp.org/).

Answer (score 6):

```
(define and-l (lambda x 
    (if (null? x)
        #t
        (if (car x) (apply and-l (cdr x)) #f))))
```

pleas notice that this is lambda **variadic**!
apply example `(and-l #t #t #f)`

or you can use it via apply procedure(as was asked)
for example `(apply and-l (list #t #t #f))`

both options are ok...

Answer (score 5):

`and` is actually a macro, whose definition is outlined [in R5RS chapter 4](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_idx_118). The notation "library syntax" on that page really means it is implemented as a macro.

Section [7.3, Derived expression types](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_7.3) gives a possible definition of the `and` macro:

```
(define-syntax and
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((and) #t)
    ((and test) test)
    ((and test1 test2 ...)
     (if test1 (and test2 ...) #f))))
```

Given this defintion, it is not possible to use `and` as a function argument to `apply`.

Answer (score 3):

In the Scheme dialect [MIT/GNU Scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/), you can use [the function `boolean/and`](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-ref/Booleans.html#index-boolean_002fand) instead of [the special form `and`](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-ref/Conditionals.html#index-and).

```
(apply boolean/and (list #t #t #f)) ;Value: #f
```

Also, for the record, I couldn’t find any equivalent function in [Guile Scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)’s [procedure index](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Procedure-Index.html#Procedure-Index).

(Other answers have already explained why the special form `and` won’t work, and shown how to write your own replacement function if there isn’t already such a function in your dialect.)

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY wanted to have a function pointer to a function that does and, and you don't mind behavior different than the "real" and, then this would work:

```
(define and-l (lambda (a b) (and a b)))
```

Which you can apply like this:

```
(apply and-l (list #t #f))
```

The two caveats are:

1. All of the args get evaluated, in violation of the definition of and, which should have shortcutting behavior.
2. Only two arguments are allowed.

Comment: `(define (and/f . xs) (cond ((null? xs) #t) ((null? (cdr xs)) (car xs)) (else (and (car xs) (apply and/f (cdr xs))))))`

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled across the same problem and found an elegant solution in Racket.
Since the problem is that "and" is a macro and not a function in order to prevent the evaluation of all its arguments, I've read a little on "lazy racket" and found that "and" is a function in *that* language. So I came up with the following solution where I just import the lazy and as "lazy-and":

```
#lang racket
(require (only-in lazy [and lazy-and]))

(define (mm)
  (map number? '(1 2 3)))

(printf "~a -> ~a\n" (mm) (apply lazy-and (mm)))
```

which yields

```
(#t #t #t) -> #t
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(define list-and (lambda (args) (and (car args) (list-and (cdr args)))))
```

then you can use apply to list-and!

Comment: This will not work as expected.  Try this instead: (define (list-and args) (if (null? args) #t (and (car args) (list-and (cdr args)))))

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

`(define (andApply lBoo)
  (if (not (car lBoo)) #f
      (if (= 1(length lBoo)) (car lBoo)
          (andApply (cdr lBoo)))))`

Answer (score -1):

I also bump into this problem playing with PLT-Scheme 372, I have digged into the behavior of and-syntax, and figure out the follow code which works just as if one would intuitively expect `(apply and lst)` to return, but I haven't done exaustive test.

```
(define (list-and lst) 
  (cond 
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((not (pair? lst)) (and lst)) 
    ((eq? (length lst) 1) (car lst))
    (else
     (and (car lst)
          (list-and (cdr lst))))
    )
  )

Welcome to DrScheme, version 372 [3m].
Language: Textual (MzScheme, includes R5RS).

> (eq? (and '()) (list-and '()))
#t
> (eq? (and '#f) (list-and (list '#f)))
#t
> (eq? (and 'a) (list-and (list 'a)))
#t
> (eq? (and 'a 'b) (list-and (list 'a 'b)))
#t
> (eq? (and 'a 'b '()) (list-and (list 'a 'b '())))
#t
> (eq? (and 'a 'b '#t) (list-and (list 'a 'b '#t)))
#t
> (eq? (and 'a 'b '#f) (list-and (list 'a 'b '#f)))
#t
```

I've also figured out another **mind-trapping** workaround. I call it **mind-trapping** because at first I don't know how to turn it into a function... Here it is (only a demo of my intuitive idea):

```
Welcome to DrScheme, version 372 [3m].
Language: Textual (MzScheme, includes R5RS).
> (eval (cons 'and (list ''#f ''#f ''#t)))
#f
> (eval (cons 'and (list ''a ''b ''c)))
c
```

But later I asked a question and got the answer here: [Is it possible to generate (quote (quote var)) or ''var dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797505/is-it-possible-to-generate-quote-quote-var-or-var-dynamically/20797614#20797614) . With this answer one can easily turn the above idea into a function.

```
(define (my-quote lst)
  (map (lambda (x) `'',x) lst))

(cons 'and (my-quote (list 'a 'b 'c)))
=> '(and ''a ''b ''c)
```

Comment: Using `eval` for this is way over the top and not recommended. In Racket, you can use `andmap` to do this: `(andmap values '(a b c))` => `c`. (In Racket, you can also use `identity` instead of `values`.)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing of `andmap` and `identity` ... Do you mean "eval ..." is something too powerful for simple task like mapping "and" onto a "list", that I cannot control it after something goes wrong with it? (Anyway, I will keep your advice in mind!)

Comment: `eval` is way too frequently misused, and can be a security concern if you don't quote everything correctly. It is also too heavyweight for what you're doing here. To me, the main use of `eval` is to run user-supplied code (with all the security implications attendant to running user-supplied code), such as in a REPL.

Comment: It sounds `eval` is beyond my understanding, at least for now. I will avoid using it for fun... unless I feel confident about it. :)