# How do I apply "or" to a list in elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

In elisp I can evaluate or as a function just like +.

```
(or nil 0 nil) ==> 0

(+ 1 0 1) ==> 2
```

I can use apply to apply + to a list

```
(apply '+ '(1 0 1)) ==> 2
```

So, I would think or would work the same way, but it doesn't.

```
(apply 'or '(nil 0 nil)) ==> error: (invalid-function or)
```

I imagine this comes from some internal magic used to implement the short-circuit evaluation.  How can I use apply to execute the or operation over a list?

---

P.S. my desired application is to find out whether any elements on the command line match a particular pattern, so the important part of what I am writing is:

```
(apply 'or (mapcar (lambda (x) (string-match-p "pattern" x)) command-line-args))
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that `or` is a macro (which is the "internal magic" in question), and you're right that that's done so it can do short-circuiting.  If `or` was a function, then calling it would need to follow the usual rules for evaluating a function call: all the arguments would need to get evaluated before the call is made.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859584/how-to-check-if-a-list-contains-only-t/5859945) -- it's about Scheme but it's the exact same issue.

As for a solution, you should probably use `some`, as in:

```
(some (lambda (x) (string-match-p "pattern" x)) command-line-args)
```

Note: this uses common lisp that is not included in emacs by default. Just use `(require 'cl)`

Comment: +1 for actually offering a solution, something that I completely forgot about.

Comment: The solution with some does not execute.  I get the error (void-function some) -- which I take to mean some is not defined.

Comment: Eponymous: `some` is defined in "cl-extra.el" -- you might need to load that first.  Or you might be using an older version of Emacs.

Comment: Yeah, you need to require it since the CL stuff is not in by default.  Just use `(require 'cl)`.

Comment: `(require 'cl-extra)` -> `(cl-some pred list)`

Comment: Yeah, that's a recent change as per the docstring of `some`.

Answer (score 10):

If it makes you feel any better, you're in good company!  This is the third question in [the "Common Pitfalls" section of the Lisp FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/lisp-faq/part3/section-3.html):

> Here's the simple, but not necessarily satisfying, answer: AND and OR are
>   macros, not functions; APPLY and FUNCALL can only be used to invoke
>   functions, not macros and special operators.

...and Eli is of course right on the money with his suggestion to use `SOME`:

> The Common Lisp functions EVERY and SOME can be used to get the
>   functionality you intend when trying to apply #'AND and #'OR.

(The FAQ and this answer are mostly about Common Lisp but in this case if you omit the `#` character the answer is the same.)

Comment: Very odd, considering `(or) is a special form defined in C source code.` as opposed to an actual macro.  (Is _special form_ the reason it doesn't work with `(apply)`?)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care performance, use `(eval (cons 'or '(nil 0 nil)))`

Comment: This answer deserves way more upvotes, but I guess people have been trained to be [afraid of eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil).

Answer (score 2):

When I was trying to 'apply' a macro to an argument list, I got an error that the function is unbound, which means that, 'apply' only receives a function, instead of a macro, as its first argument.

In order to fix this, I wrote a new function 'apply-macro' as follows:

```
(defun apply-macro (macro arg-list)
  (eval
   `(,macro ,@(loop for arg in arg-list
                 collect `(quote ,arg)))))
```

For instance, I wrote a macro to concatenate multiple lists together:

```
(defmacro conc-lists (&rest lists)
  `(funcall #'concatenate 'list ,@lists))
```

e.g.
    (conc-lists '(a b) '(c d) '(e f)) ;;=> (A B C D E F)

Now try 'apply-macro':

```
(apply-macro 'conc-lists '((a b) (c d) (e f)))
```

It works and returns the same output.

In fact, it will be expanded into:

```
(eval
   (conc-lists (quote (a b)) (quote (c d)) (quote (e f))))
```

You can also pass a form to a macro:

```
(apply-macro 'conc-lists (maplist #'list '(a b c)))
;;=> ((A B C) (B C) (C))
```

Get back to your question, it's solved:

```
(apply-macro 'or '(nil 0 nil)) ;;=> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing here, but I think `or` might be one of these 20-odd 'functions' in lisp that are not really functions, since they don't always evaluate all parameters.

This makes sense to make `or` one of these, since if you have found one TRUE, you can stop searching. In other words, `or` is not a function as a form of optimization. Still only guessing though.

Comment: I was thinking of special operators, which are neither macros nor functions. I heard there are 25 of them (at least in clisp). I don't know much more about them than that, but I'm pretty sure I made a mistake saying `or` is one of them.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, there is a difference between special forms and macros -- the former are part of the language, and the latter are not.  In the ELisp case, `or` happens to have been defined as a primitive builtin, but that's just an implementation issue since it could just as well have been defined as a macro using `if`.  (And ELisp doesn't try to get to some minimalism, or it would have done just that.)

Answer (score 0):

[Eli Barzilay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5902980/596361) is correct and idiomatic. I want to provide an alternative answer based on [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), the library I use to write terse [functional-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) code, when I have to work with lists. `or` returns the *first* non-nil element, nil otherwise, due to short-circuiting. Therefore simply use [`-first`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-first-pred-list):

```
(-first 'identity '(nil 0 1 nil)) ; 0
(-first 'identity '(nil nil)) ; nil
```

`identity` function simply returns its argument. Which is clever, because `-first` applies a predicate until it returns non-nil. `identity` returns non-nil if the argument is itself non-nil. If you simply want to test whether there is non-nil elements in a list, use [`-any?`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-any-pred-list) instead:

```
(-any? 'identity '(nil 0 1 nil)) ; t
(-any? 'identity '(nil nil)) ; nil
```

Comment: In this context, there's also `(-flatten <list>)`