# pass a list to macro in Common Lisp

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, metaprogramming, quote

I'm having a problem passing a list to macro, where the list will be used to generate function name. For example, the code below causes an error.

```
(defmacro gen (str-lst)
  `(defun ,(intern (string-upcase (car str-lst))) () (print "foo")))

(gen '("foo" "bar"))
```

The resulting error was:

> *** - DEFUN/DEFMACRO: QUOTE is a special operator and may not be redefined. The following restarts are available: ABORT          :R1
>   Abort main loop

How should I modify my code, and what is wrong with my code?

The thing makes me even more confused is that the code below, about which answer exits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196080/how-to-pass-a-list-to-macro-in-common-lispj), works fine.

```
(defmacro easy-one (str-lst)
  `(mapc #'(lambda (str) (print str)) ,str-lst))
(easy-one '("foo" "bar"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't quote the list. Macros don't evaluate their arguments, so you don't need to quote them to prevent them from being evaluated, like you do for ordinary functions.

```
(gen ("foo" "bar"))
```

When you quote it, you're executing

```
(get (quote ("foo" "bar")))
```

The value of `str-list` is the list `(quote ("foo" "bar"))`, so `(car str-list)` is the symbol `QUOTE`. As a result, the macro expands to

```
(defun quote () (print "foo"))
```

That's why you get an error complaining that you're trying to redefine the built-in `QUOTE`.

The difference in your second example is that you're just substituting the parameter into the expansion, you're not using its value in the expansion code. So it expands to

```
(mapc #'(lambda (str) (print str)) '("foo" "bar")))
```

Here the list will be used when the expansion runs, not while the macro is being expanded. It needs to be quoted there, to prevent it from being evaluated as a function call.

You should use `macroexpand` to see how your macros are being expanded when debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, then, how can I pass an variable formally declared? For example, how about declaring like `(defparameter str-lst '("foo" "bar"))` and then substituting it into the macro?

Comment: You can't do that. Macros are expanded at compile time, the variable doesn't exist until run time.

Comment: If you want to define a function at run time, you can use `eval`: ```(eval `(gen ,str-list))```