# how do I pass a list to a common lisp macro?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am trying to compare the performance of a function and a macro.

EDIT: Why do I want to compare the two?
Paul Graham wrote in his ON LISP  book that macros can be used to make a system more efficient because a lot of the computation can be done at compile time. so in the example below `(length args)` is dealt with at compile time in the macro case and at run time in the function case. So, I just wanted how much faster did `(avg2 super-list)` get computed relative to `(avg super-list)`.

Here is the function and the macro:

```
(defun avg (args)
   (/ (apply #'+ args) (length args)))

(defmacro avg2 (args)
  `(/ (+ ,@args) ,(length args)))
```

I have looked at this question [How to pass a list to macro in common lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196080/how-to-pass-a-list-to-macro-in-common-lisp) and a few other ones but they do not help because their solutions do not work; for example, in one of the questions a user answered by saying to do this:

```
(avg2 (2 3 4 5))
```

instead of this:

```
(avg2 '(2 3 4))
```

This works but I want a list containg 100,000 items:

```
(defvar super-list (loop for i from 1 to 100000 collect i))
```

But this doesnt work.

So, how can I pass `super-list` to `avg2`?

Comment: see the Common Lisp variable CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT for the maximum possible number of arguments to a function.

Comment: the value of CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT can be as low as 50 in some implementations. See also the function REDUCE to use instead.

Comment: you try to compute in the macro the length of the args. Which does not work, since the ARGs list is the code, not the computed list. If you actually compute the list at macro expansion time, then you can also do the rest at macroexpansion time and the AVG2 macro just inserts the result number into the code. Thus the macro call has basically no runtime in compiled code.

Comment: It makes no sense to compare the performance of a macro and a function.

Comment: comparing the performance of a function to a that of a macro makes sense because macros can do a lot of computation  at compile time. so in this example `(length args)` is evaluated when the program is running in the case of the function and at dealt with at compile time in the case of the macro. this makes it more efficient. i wanted to know how much more efficient was a macro.

Comment: @aSphereInAManifold Macros are there to extend the semantic capabilities of Common Lisp (basically to do things you cannot do in functions) and functions are there to perform operations. Comparing the performance of a macro and a function is on par with comparing a puppy and an orange for the best suitability as a building material. It simply makes no sense, other than to someone not familiar with the language.

Comment: @Vatine I dont think you guys understood my question. macros can also be used for efficiency because some of the computation can be done at compile time. so i think youre less familiar than me about macros. go read ON LISP by Paul Graham ;)

Comment: this question was not about efficiency either. the question was about how to pass a list to a macro. please read the question carefully.

Comment: @aSphereInAManifold I think I understood your question just fine. It is coming from a position of "I want to do X, why doesn't Y work?"-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it simply makes no sense to 'compare the performance of a function and a macro'.  It only makes sense to compare the performance of the *expansion* of a macro with a function.  So that's what I'll do.

Secondly, it only makes sense to compare the performance of a function with the expansion of a macro if that macro is equivalent to the function.  In other words the only places this comparison is useful is where the macro is being used as a hacky way of inlining a function.  It doesn't make sense to compare the performance of something which a function can't express, like `if` or `and` say.  So we must rule out all the interesting uses of macros.

Thirdly it makes no sense to compare the performance of things which are broken: it is very easy to make programs which do not work be as fast as you like.  So I'll successively modify both your function and macro so they're not broken.

Fourthly it makes no sense to compare the performance of things which use algorithms which are gratuitously terrible, so I'll modify both your function and your macro to use better algrorithms.

Finally it makes no sense to compare the performance of things without using the tools the language provides to encourage good performance, so I will do that as the last step.

---

So let's address the third point above: let's see how `avg` (and therefore `avg2`) is broken.

Here's the broken definition of `avg` from the question:

```
(defun avg (args)
   (/ (apply #'+ args) (length args)))
```

So let's try it:

```
>  (let ((l (make-list 1000000 :initial-element 0)))
     (avg l))

Error: Last argument to apply is too long: 1000000
```

Oh dear, as other people have pointed out.  So probably I need instead to make `avg` at least work.  As other people have, again, pointed out, the way to do this is `reduce`:

```
(defun avg (args)
  (/ (reduce #'+ args) (length args)))
```

And now a call to `avg` works, at least.  `avg` is now non-buggy.

We need to make `avg2` non-buggy as well.  Well, first of all the `(+ ,@args)` thing is a non-starter: `args` is a symbol at macroexpansion time, not a list.  So we could try this `(apply #'+ ,args)` (the expansion of the macro is now starting to look a bit like the body of the function, which is unsurprising!).  So given

```
(defmacro avg2 (args)
  `(/ (apply #'+ ,args) (length ,args)))
```

We get

```
> (let ((l (make-list 1000000 :initial-element 0)))
    (avg2 l))

Error: Last argument to apply is too long: 1000000
```

OK, unsurprising again.  let's fix it to use `reduce` again:

```
(defmacro avg2 (args)
  `(/ (reduce #'+ ,args) (length ,args)))
```

So now it 'works'.  Except it doesn't: it's not safe.  Look at this:

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(avg2 (make-list 1000000 :initial-element 0)))
(/ (reduce #'+ (make-list 1000000 :initial-element 0))
   (length (make-list 1000000 :initial-element 0)))
t
```

That definitely is not right: it will be enormously slow but also it will just be buggy.  We need to fix the multiple-evaluation problem.

```
(defmacro avg2 (args)
  `(let ((r ,args))
     (/ (reduce #'+ r) (length r))))
```

This is safe in all sane cases.  So this is now a reasonably safe 70s-style what-I-really-want-is-an-inline-function macro.

So, let's write a test-harness both for `avg` and `avg2`.  You will need to recompile `av2` each time you change `avg2` and in fact you'll need to recompile `av1` for a change we're going to make to `avg` as well.  Also make sure everything is compiled!

```
(defun av0 (l)
  l)

(defun av1 (l)
  (avg l))

(defun av2 (l)
  (avg2 l))

(defun test-avg-avg2 (nelements niters)
  ;; Return time per call in seconds per iteration per element
  (let* ((l (make-list nelements :initial-element 0))
         (lo (let ((start (get-internal-real-time)))
               (dotimes (i niters (- (get-internal-real-time) start))
                 (av0 l)))))
    (values
     (let ((start (get-internal-real-time)))
       (dotimes (i niters (float (/ (- (get-internal-real-time) start lo)
                                    internal-time-units-per-second
                                    nelements niters)))
         (av1 l)))
     (let ((start (get-internal-real-time)))
       (dotimes (i niters (float (/ (- (get-internal-real-time) start lo)
                                    internal-time-units-per-second
                                    nelements niters)))
         (av2 l))))))
```

So now we can test various combinations.

OK, so now the fouth point: both `avg` and `avg2` use awful algorithms: they traverse the list twice.  Well we can fix this:

```
(defun avg (args)
  (loop for i in args
        for c upfrom 0
        summing i into s
        finally (return (/ s c))))
```

and similarly

```
(defmacro avg2 (args)
  `(loop for i in ,args
         for c upfrom 0
         summing i into s
         finally (return (/ s c))))
```

These changes made a performance difference of about a factor of 4 for me.

OK so now the final point: we should use the tools the language gives us.  As has been clear throughout this whole exercise only make sense if you're using a macro as a poor-person's inline function, as people had to do in the 1970s.

But it's not the 1970s any more: we have inline functions.

So:

```
(declaim (inline avg))
(defun avg (args)
  (loop for i in args
        for c upfrom 0
        summing i into s
        finally (return (/ s c))))
```

And now you will have to make sure you recompile `avg` and then `av1`.  And when I look at `av1` and `av2` I can now see that they are the same code: the entire purpose of `avg2` has now gone.

Indeed we can do even better than this:

```
(define-compiler-macro avg (&whole form l &environment e)
  ;; I can't imagine what other constant forms there might be in this
  ;; context, but, well, let's be safe
  (if (and (constantp l e)
           (listp l)
           (eql (first l) 'quote))
      (avg (second l))
    form))
```

Now we have something which:

- has the semantics of a function, so, say `(funcall #'avg ...)` will work;
- isn't broken;
- uses a non-terrible algorithm;
- will be inlined on any competent implementation of the language (which I bet is 'all implementations' now) when it can be;
- will detect (some?) cases where it can be compiled completely away and replaced by a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2):

Since the value of super-list is known, one can do all computation at macro expansion time:

```
(eval-when (:execute :compile-toplevel :load-toplevel)
  (defvar super-list (loop for i from 1 to 100000 collect i)))

(defmacro avg2 (args)
  (setf args (eval args))
  (/ (reduce #'+ args) (length args)))

(defun test ()
  (avg2 super-list))
```

Trying the compiled code:

```
CL-USER 10 > (time (test))
Timing the evaluation of (TEST)

User time    =        0.000
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.000
Allocation   = 0 bytes
0 Page faults
100001/2
```

Thus the runtime is near zero.

The generated code is just a number, the result number:

```
CL-USER 11 > (macroexpand '(avg2 super-list))
100001/2
```

Thus for known input this macro call in compiled code has a constant runtime of near zero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want a list of 100,000 items. That would have terrible performance with all that cons'ing. You should consider a vector instead, e.g.

```lisp
(avg2 #(2 3 4))
```

You didn't mention why it didn't work; if the function never returns, it's likely a memory issue from such a large list, or attempting to `apply` on such a large function argument list; there are implementation defined limits on how many arguments you can pass to a function.

Try `reduce` on a super-vector instead:

```lisp
(reduce #'+ super-vector)
```

Comment: this is an off topic answer, i think. i want to compare the performance of the function and macro not how to process 100000 items efficiently. if you try to pass 'super-list' to the macro it doesnt work because macros dont work like that. hence my question.