# In elisp, how do I apply backquote to lists read from files

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to take a large list (think faces in an emacs theme) and break it up into smaller lists in separate files.  The problem I have is applying `(backquote)` to the lists once I've read them in.

Here is the code I have been using to experiment with solutions:

```
(defvar x 23)

(defun read-from-file (file)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (read (current-buffer))))

;;(defun apply-macro (macro arg-list)
;;  (eval
;;   `(,macro ,@(loop for arg in arg-list
;;                    collect `(quote ,arg)))))

(defvar parts (mapcar 'read-from-file (directory-files "./parts/" "parts/" "\.part$")))

;;(apply-macro 'backquote parts)

parts
```

This code relies on "data" files in a subdirectory called `parts/`.  Here are some samples:

1. `parts/one.part`
       `( ("one" "two" "three") ("ten" ,x "twelve") )
   **NOTE: the `,x` in this one.  I want to have this evaluated after the expression is read from the file.**
2. `parts/two.part`
       ( ("four" "five" "six") (2 4 6) (9 87 6) )
3. `parts/three.part`
       (("seven" "eight" "nine"))

Reading the "part" files is no problem.  The `(defvar parts (mapcar ... )` expression works.

The problem is that once I have the lists in the `parts` var, I cannot find a way to get the `,x` evaluated as it would be if the whole list was backquoted and not read from files.

I have tried [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34946813/6015764) suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902847/how-do-i-apply-or-to-a-list-in-elisp).  You can see the `apply-macro` function commented out in my code above.  When I run it I get:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments #[(structure) "\301!A\207" [structure backquote-process] 2 1628852] 3)
  #[(structure) "\301!A\207" [structure backquote-process] 2 1628852]((quote (\` (("one" "two" "three") ("ten" (\, x) "twelve")))) (quote (("seven" "eight" "nine"))) (quote (("four" "five" "six") (2 4 6) (9 87 6))))
  (backquote (quote (\` (("one" "two" "three") ("ten" (\, x) "twelve")))) (quote (("seven" "eight" "nine"))) (quote (("four" "five" "six") (2 4 6) (9 87 6))))
  eval((backquote (quote (\` (("one" "two" "three") ("ten" (\, x) "twelve")))) (quote (("seven" "eight" "nine"))) (quote (("four" "five" "six") (2 4 6) (9 87 6)))))
  apply-macro(backquote ((\` (("one" "two" "three") ("ten" (\, x) "twelve"))) (("seven" "eight" "nine")) (("four" "five" "six") (2 4 6) (9 87 6))))
  eval-region(648 678 t #[257 "\300\242b\210\301\207" [(678) (apply-macro (quote backquote) parts)] 2 "\n\n(fn IGNORE)"])  ; Reading at buffer position 651
  eval-defun-2()
  #[257 "\211\203
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backquote does interesting things. In Emacs lisp the returned value from reading a quasi-quoted list is a list of the following structure:

```
ELISP> (defvar x (car (read-from-string "`(1 2 ,x)")))

ELISP> (car x)
\`

ELISP> (cdr x)
((1 2
    (\, x)))

ELISP> (caddr (cadr x))
(\, x)

ELISP> (consp (caddr (cadr x)))
t
```

So, if you intend on using quasi-quoted lists, you might need to perform the replacement your self. For example, you can do:

```
(defun replace-item (item new-item seq)
  (let ((found-item (member item seq)))
    (when found-item
      (setf (car found-item) new-item))
    seq))


ELISP> (replace-item '(\, x) 'z (cadr x))
(1 2 z)
```

PS. Common Lisp does something weird with comma characters, after reading the same list `,X` becomes an object of type `SB-IMPL::COMMA` (in SBCL): it's neither a symbol, nor a pair.

PPS. Somehow those quasi-quotes and commas are treated specially by the reader-evaluator, to the point that the combo `(eval (read <...>))` does not produce the same result as internal evaluator.

### Something that works

While playing around with back-quotes and commas, I found that the following works, although it's quite a bit of hack.

First, don't back-quote your structures: it doesn't do any harm, but it wouldn't introduce anything either. Just have `(a b ,c)`.

When you read it (either with `read` from file or with `read-from-string`), it will be transformed into:

```
ELISP> (setq x (car (read-from-string "(a b ,c)")))
(a b
   (\, c))
```

Now, the piece of magic: there is macro `backquote` that does the substitution, but it accepts a *structure*: it does not evaluate its argument, so to make it act on `x` have to do the following:

```
ELISP> (let ((c 10)) (eval `(backquote ,x)))
(a b 10)
```

As you can see `(\, c)` was replaced by local binding of `c` as wanted.

PPPS. One would expect that reading from string `"`(a b ,c)"`would produce`(backquote (a b ,c))` but it doesn't.

I hope this provides the answer.

Comment: thanks.  It looks like I would be making a `replace-item` call for each symbol I want to replace.  e.g.  If my lists in files contained ,x  ,y ,whatever then I would need to call replace-item for each of these.  I guess I can find all the comma parts that need replacing and map over them or something, but it would be better if there was a way for backquote to be applied.

Comment: @HenryBone I think I found the way to make Elisp to do what you want: I have updated the answer.

Comment: @HenryBone In fact, it can be even simpler: `(let ((c 10)) (eval (car (read-from-string "`(a b ,c)")))) => (a b 10)`

Comment: Thank you @mobiuseng.  Have a tick.  :-)