# "cond","and" and "or" in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm reading *The Little Schemer*. And thanks to my broken English, I was confused by this paragraph:

> (cond ... ) also has the property of not considering all of its
>   arguments. Because of this property, however, neither (and ... ) nor
>   (or ... ) can be defined as functions in terms of (cond ... ), though
>   both (and ... ) and (or ... ) can be expressed as abbreviations of
>   (cond ... )-expressions:
>
> ```
> (and a b) = (cond (a b) (else #f) 
>     and 
> (or a b) = (cond (a #t) (else (b))
> ```

If I understand it correctly, it says (and ...) and (or ...) can be replaced by a (cond ...) expression, but cannot be defined as a function that contains (cond ...). Why is it so? Does it have anything to do with the variant arguments? Thanks.

p.s. I did some searching but only found that (cond ...) ignores the expressions when one of its conditions evaluate to #f.

Comment: In addition to the answers that you get here, you might look at the answers to [Why (apply and '(1 2 3)) doesn't work while (and 1 2 3) works in R5RS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17232240/1281433) and [Using AND with the apply function in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387775/using-and-with-the-apply-function-in-scheme).  The topic of the questions is a little different than your question, but the answers explain some of the same concepts.

Comment: Thank you! The two posts are quite enlightening. Now I think I need to read the SICP.

Comment: It's well worth the read, and it's [available for free online](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine you wrote `if` as a function/procedure rather than a user defined macro/syntax:

```
;; makes if in terms of cond
(define (my-if predicate consequent alternative)
  (cond (predicate consequent)
        (else alternative)))

;; example that works
(define (atom? x)
  (my-if (not (pair? x))
         #t
         #f))

;; example that won't work
;; peano arithemtic
(define (add a b)
  (my-if (zero? a)
         b
         (add (- a 1) (+ b 1))))
```

The problem with `my-if` is that as a procedure every argument gets evaluated before the procedure body gets executed. thus in `atom?` the parts `(not (pair? x))`, `#t` and `#f` were evaluated before the body of `my-if` gets executed.

For the last example means `(add (- a 1) (+ b 1))` gets evaluated regardless of what a is, even when `a` is zero, so the procedure will never end.

You can make your own if with syntax:

```
(define-syntax my-if
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((my-if predicate consequent alternative)
     (cond (predicate consequent)
           (else alternative)))))
```

Now, how you read this is the first part is a template where the predicate consequent and alternative represent unevaluated expressions. It's replaced with the other just reusing the expressions so that:

```
(my-if (check-something) (display 10) (display 20))
```

would be replaced with this:

```
(cond ((check-something) (display 10))
      (else (display 20)))
```

With the procedure version of `my-if` both 10 and 20 would have been printed. This is how `and` and `or` is implemented as well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define `cond` or `and` or `or` or `if` as *functions* because functions evaluate all their arguments. (You could define some of them as macros).

Read also the famous [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) ([original](http://paracamplus.com/?CGIRunMode=book&urn=Cours/LiSP/4) in French).

Comment: Thank you! This book is great, except that it doesn't tell so many details about the language.