# Is it possible to generate (quote (quote var)) or ''var dynamically?

Tags: scheme, quote

In question [Using AND with the apply function in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387775/using-and-with-the-apply-function-in-scheme/20780866#20780866) , I proposed an solution to apply "and" onto a list of atoms (i.e. s-exp which is neither null, nor pair.) in PLT-Scheme 372.

```
Welcome to DrScheme, version 372 [3m].
Language: Textual (MzScheme, includes R5RS).
> (eval (cons 'and (list ''#f ''#f ''#t)))
#f
> (eval (cons 'and (list ''a ''b ''c)))
c
```

But right after that I realized that: it's not easy to generate `(quote (quote var))` or `''var` dynamically. To be specific, the following code will not work:

```
(define (my-quote lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    (else
     (cons (quote (car lst))
           (my-quote (cdr lst)))
     )))

Welcome to DrScheme, version 372 [3m].
Language: Textual (MzScheme, includes R5RS).
> (my-quote (list 'a 'b 'c))
((car lst) (car lst) (car lst))
```

as `(car lst)` will not be evaluated in the first place; And even if I `(let ((var (car list))) (quote var))`, it will not work, either, as var will not be evaluated.

My question is, is there some sort of mind trap in my attempting to do this?

Comment: The use of `eval` to run programmatically-generated code in this way is not a good idea, sorry. The standard way to dynamically generate code (at compile time) is to use a macro, and writing a macro is definitely to be preferred to using `eval` where it's feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually as easy as it gets:

```
(list 'quote (list 'quote var))
```

Comment: And it does appeal to me a little more, intuitively. I should wait a few minutes to see if there would be simpler answer just now... But let me wait until tomorrow to decide which answer to toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
(define (my-quote lst)
  (map (lambda (x) `',x) lst))
```

then

```
(cons 'and (my-quote (list 'a 'b 'c)))
=> '(and 'a 'b 'c)
```

If you want more quotes, just add them in the procedure:

```
(define (my-quote lst)
  (map (lambda (x) `'',x) lst))

(cons 'and (my-quote (list 'a 'b 'c)))
=> '(and ''a ''b ''c)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted... I admit that I haven't carefully read through any scheme manual to learn various "quote" syntax, but your sample code let me focus on usage of "`" now! Thanks very much!

Comment: *`'',var* is the same thing as *(list 'quote (list 'quote var))* ... just shorter.

Comment: I really love your answer, it help me discover new "overlooked knowledge assets", but for this question, I would like to toggle the longer answer, for it looks more intuitive and make code easier to read for peer developers. :D

Comment: No problem whatsoever ;-)

Comment: I've visited your personal about page, it's awesome, so glad to know you! :)