# why `and` operator in scheme is not an built-in procedure

Tags: scheme, lisp

I use chicken Scheme interpreter, and when I type `not`, it returns `#<procedure (not x295)>`, but when I tried `and` and `or`, it returns `Error: unbound variable: and`.

It seems that the `and` operator is not a built-in procedure, why it is different from `not`?

And if this is true, how is `(and #t #f)` evaluated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using AND with the apply function in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387775/using-and-with-the-apply-function-in-scheme)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`and` and `or` are "short-circuit operators" - they will not evaluate more than necessary for the result to be formed, just like `if` and `cond`. For example:

```
(and #f (display "foo"))
```

will not display anything, and neither will this:

```
(or #t (display "foo"))
```

It is impossible to do this with procedures, because a call to a procedure will evaluate all the arguments before the procedure is entered:

```
(define (proc-or x y) (if x #t (if y #t #f)))
(proc-or #t (display "foo"))
; displays "foo" anyway
```

A special form like `if` (or, indeed, `or`) can decide which parameters it wishes to evaluate. Refer to any Scheme manual regarding conditional operators, or more generally special forms (e.g. [MIT Scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Conditionals.html), [Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html)...)

More specifically, `or` and `and` will be either primitive forms (like `if`), or macros that translate the operator into a sequence of primitive forms.

Comment: With lazy evaluation it is possible to do this with procedures/functions. Therefore it is not a question of primitives vs procedures.

Comment: But Scheme R5RS specification does not allow lazy evaluations. It requires an eager evaluation (for most procedure calls).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Only "most"?

Comment: @knivil Other than special forms and macros, standard evaluation rules (i.e., eager evaluation) apply. That's why `and` and `or` are macros.