# In Scheme, does `or` and `and` short circuit?

Tags: scheme, short-circuiting, short-circuit-evaluation

Do `and` and `or` short circuit in Scheme?

The following are two implementation of `lat?` (list of atoms). One uses `cond` … `else` and the other uses `or` and `and`. I was wondering if they are equivalent and the answer to that hinges on whether `or` and `and` have short circuit evaluation in Scheme.

```
(define lat?
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
         ((null? l) #t)
         ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l)))
         (else #f))))
```

- uses `cond` and `else`

---

```
(define lat?
  (lambda (l)
    (or (null? l)
        (and (atom? (car l))
             (lat? (cdr l))))))
```

- uses `or` and `and`

I think `or` short-circuits. Why? I know `(car ())` and `(cdr ())` each produce `Error: Attempt to apply…`. If `or` didn’t short-circuit, then `(lat? ())` would eventually evaluate `(car ())` and produce the error. However, `(lat? ())` does not produce the error, therefore (via Modus Tollens) `or` short-circuits. Is this correct? And does `and` short-circuit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why \`and\` operator in scheme is not an built-in procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902224/why-and-operator-in-scheme-is-not-an-built-in-procedure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they both short-circuit per [r6rs specification](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.5) (didn't find  html version of r7rs online but here a link to the pdf version of [r7rs specification](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf), see section 4.2):

> If there are no `<test>s`, `#t` is returned. Otherwise, the  expressions are evaluated from left to right until a `<test>` returns #f or the last `<test>` is reached. In the former case, the and expression returns `#f` *without evaluating the remaining expressions*. In the latter case, the last expression is evaluated and its values are returned.

`and` & `or` is subsequently defined in terms of `test`.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to say that I found your first edit easier to understand at a glance.

Comment: Yeah, I know, specifications are formal and usually harder to read. The first edit was to class website and not a specification as I claimed.