# why does apply map and to list of expressions returns only one boolean?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (cart . lists)
  (cond ((null? lists) '())
        ((= (length lists) 1) (map list (first lists)))
        (else
         (append-map (lambda(x)
                       (map (lambda(y) (cons y x))
                            (first lists)))
                     (apply cart (rest lists))))))

(define (numbers n)
   (define (reversed-numbers n)
     (if (= n 0)
         '()
         `(,n . ,(reversed-numbers (- n 1)))))
   (reverse (reversed-numbers n)))

(define (gen-truth n vals)
       (apply cart (map (lambda(x) list vals) (numbers n))))

(gen-truth 2 '(#t #f))  returns: '((#t #t) (#f #t) (#t #f) (#f #f))

(define and-l (lambda x 
    (if (null? x)
        #t
        (if (car x) (apply and-l (cdr x)) #f))))
```

why does:    `(apply map and-l (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))`

return `'(#f #f)` ? i would expect it return a Boolean for each of the sub expressions containing pairs of Boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### A Better `and-l` Procedure

---

The problem is that the `and-l` procedure is operating in a way that probably was not anticipated. Here, `x` is put into a list before being passed along to the body of the procedure. Consider:

```
scratch.rkt> (define bad-proc (lambda x x))
scratch.rkt> (bad-proc '(#t #f))
'((#t #f))
```

One would probably expect the `and-l` procedure to test whether a list contains all true values, and the one passed to the body of the procedure does:

```
scratch.rkt> (and-l-bad '(#t #f))
#t
scratch.rkt> (and-l-bad '(#f #f))
#t
scratch.rkt> (and-l-bad '(#t #t))
#t
```

Here is a correct version of `and-l`; note that there is no need for `apply`:

```
(define and-l
  (lambda (x)
    (if (null? x)
        #t
        (and (car x) (and-l (cdr x))))))
```

Testing the new procedure:

```
scratch.rkt> (and-l '(#t #f))
#f
scratch.rkt> (and-l '(#f #f))
#f
scratch.rkt> (and-l '(#t #t))
#t
```

Now that `and-l` is working as it should, we turn our attention to:

```
(apply map and-l (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))
```

Again, there is no need for `apply` here. It does not even make sense here to do `(apply map and-l ;....)`. The `apply` procedure takes a procedure and a list as arguments, and uses the elements of the list as arguments to the procedure. So, `(apply + '(1 2 3 4))` is equivalent to `(+ 1 2 3 4)`. This capability is not needed in the current context; all that is needed is `map` to apply `and-l` to each list of booleans in the list returned by `gen-truth`:

```
scratch.rkt> (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f))
'((#t #t) (#f #t) (#t #f) (#f #f))
scratch.rkt> (map and-l (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))
'(#t #f #f #f)
```

---

### Salvaging the Original `and-l` Procedure

---

Note that `and-l-bad` works not on a list of arguments, but on an unspecified number of arguments which are wrapped in a list and passed to the procedure body:

```
scratch.rkt> (and-l-bad #t #f #f)
#f
scratch.rkt> (and-l-bad #t #t #t)
#t
scratch.rkt> (and-l-bad #f #f #t)
#f
```

With this in mind, OP goal can be achieved without rewriting `and-l-bad` to `and-l` as above. Instead, rethink `(apply map and-l (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))`:

```
scratch.rkt> (map (lambda (x) (apply and-l-bad x)) (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))
'(#t #f #f #f)
```

Here, `map` applies a function to each boolean list in the list returned by `gen-truth`. That function takes a boolean list and applies `apply` with `and-l-bad` to it, so that,e.g. `(apply and-l-bad '(#t #f)` --> `(and-l-bad #t #f)`, which is exactly what `and-l-bad` is expecting.

---

### and-proc

---

The procedure `and-l-bad` is really like `and`, in that it takes an unspecified number of arguments and returns the result of combining the arguments with `and`:

```
scratch.rkt> (and-l-bad #t #t #f #t)
#f
scratch.rkt> (and #t #t #f #t)
#f
```

But there is an important difference: `and-l-bad` is a *procedure*, while `and` is a *special form*. Procedures always evaluate *all* of their arguments, but special forms have special evaluation rules. The special form `and` evaluates its arguments sequentially until the result is known, either returning the first `#f` encountered in that sequence, or the last value of the sequence. This is *short-circuit evaluation*.

A better name for `and-l-bad` would perhaps be `and-proc`. The original name, `and-l` suggested that `and` was applied to a list (which was not true), while `and-proc` emphasizes that this is a *procedure* which behaves similarly to `and`.

Why would you need something like `and-proc` in the first place? Well, `apply` takes a procedure for its first argument, so `(map (lambda (x) (apply and x)) (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))` will not work. But this will work:

```
scratch.rkt> (map (lambda (x) (apply and-proc x)) (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))
'(#t #f #f #f)
```

Here we have used an `and`-like *procedure* where `and` itself would not work. The downside of `and-proc` is that it always evaluates *all* of its arguments; this is not always desirable.

---

### How to Avoid Writing a New `and`-like Procedure

---

Writing a new procedure to handle using `and` here could have been avoided altogether:

```
scratch.rkt> (map (lambda (x) (andmap identity x)) (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))
'(#t #f #f #f)
```

Here `(lambda (x) (andmap identity x))` is a procedure that takes its arguments and combines them with `and`. That is, `((lambda (x) (andmap identity x)) '(#t #f))` is equivalent to `(and (identity #t) (identity #f))`. This procedure is mapped over the list of boolean lists as before.

This is equivalent to the `and-l` defined at the top of this answer, and `and-l` could in fact be better-defined as:

```
(define (and-l xs)
  (andmap identity xs))
```

Comment: still having trouble recognizing when to use apply and where it's not needed.

Comment: If you have a function that takes, say 3 arguments, you call it like: `(func x y z)`. But what if you have the three arguments wrapped up in a list, `'(x y z)`, but you want to call that same function on those three arguments? Then you call it with `apply`: `(apply func '(x y z))`.

Comment: the broken and-l is from the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387775/using-and-with-the-apply-function-in-scheme

Comment: @X10D -- that answer points out: "_please notice that this is lambda variadic! apply example `(and-l #t #t #f)`_". It was not meant to take a list argument, but an unspecified number of arguments instead. The name `and-l` was misleading, in my opinion, but it does work as advertised.

Comment: @X10D -- There is a way to use the `and-l` procedure that you got from the other answer; it just requires rethinking your `map` expression. I have updated my answer.

Comment: what's the difference between:
(apply map and-l (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f))) and (map (lambda (x) (apply and-l x)) (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))

Comment: @X10D -- the second one maps the lambda expression over the result of `gen-truth` (which is a list); that lamda expression applies `and-l` to the elements of that list (which are boolean lists). The first one makes no sense. It attempts to apply `map` to a list with the procedure `and-l` as the first element, and the result of `gen-truth` as the tail of that list.

Comment: @X10D -- reading about [apply](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) and about [list*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%2A%29%29) might help you make sense of what `(apply map and-l (gen-truth 2 '(#t #f)))` is attempting to do.

Comment: follow up question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240991/is-this-embedding-of-or-which-is-a-macro-to-provide-short-circuiting-into-a-fun