# Calling `and` on a list of arguments

Tags: racket

Is there a way to call `and` or `or` to a list of arguments? Like

```
(and (list #t #t #f))
```

?

I tried writing `(apply and (list #t #t #f))` but that didn't work.

Comment: This Q&A is relevant: [Why does apply map and to list of expressions returns only one boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334629/why-does-apply-map-and-to-list-of-expressions-returns-only-one-boolean)

Answer (score 4):

Try [`ormap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._ormap%29%29) and [`andmap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29)

```
(ormap values (list #t #t #f))
(andmap values (list #t #t #f))
```

where [`values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html?q=values#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._values%29%29) is essentially an identity function in this context.

The reason `(apply and (list #t #t #f))` doesn't work is that `and` is not a function. It's a macro, which is necessary because `(and #f (error 'foo))` should short-circuit (evaluate to `#f`). If it were a function, it would cause the error.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do so without calling `values`?

Comment: Couldn't you just define your own function that consumes a list and invokes `ormap` with appropriate arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`any?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/relation/Logical_Relations.html#%28def._%28%28lib._relation%2Flogic..rkt%29._any%7E3f%29%29) and [`all?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/relation/Logical_Relations.html#%28def._%28%28lib._relation%2Flogic..rkt%29._all%7E3f%29%29) from the `relation` library (disclosure: I'm the author):

```
(require relation)

(any? (list #t #t #f)) ;=> #t
(all? (list #t #t #f)) ;=> #f
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on a previous answer. A poor man's way of doing it would be.

```
 > (ormap (lambda (x) (not (false? x))) (list #t #t #f))
 ## #t

 > (andmap (lambda (x) (not (false? x))) (list #t #t #f))
 ## #f
```

Comment: Why make the lambda so complicated? You could just have it be `(ormap (λ (x) x) (list #t #t #f)` and it would serve the same purpose, or even better `(ormap identity (list #t #t #f))`